# Is the zero 4-vector lightlike?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, vectors, definition

I'm not sure whether the zero 4-vector can be considered lightlike, spacelike, or timelike in special relativity. Can anybody give me some insight?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: If we define lightlike vectors as those that satisfy $g(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{v})=0$, then yes sure, the zero 4-vector is lightlike. However, I suppose some sources consider it to be none of the above. But why are you asking really? Is there something deeper here or do you just want to be careful with the terminology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three equivalence classes of zero-norm vectors under the Lorentz group: future lightlike, past lightlike, and the zero vector. I'm not entirely sure, because it's so rare to talk about the zero vector at all, but my impression is that "lightlike" usually includes just the first two categories, while "null" may include all three.

You could also make a case for treating it as timelike or spacelike, or for not doing so. I think it's usually put in a category by itself.